# How do I use Elasticsearch's geo_point and geo_shape types at the same time?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is our **document**:

```
{
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -87.662682, 41.843014 ]
    }
}
```

We'd like to do a `geo_shape` search with a `_geo_distance` sort, both against the same `geometry` field. The former requires`geo_shape` types while the latter requires `geo_point`.

These two **indexes** succeed individually, but *not together*:

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "geo_shape"
}
```

and

```
"geometry": {
    "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }
},
```

So far we've tried these and **failed**:

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "geo_shape"
},
"geometry.coordinates": {
    "type": "geo_point"
},
```

also

```
"geometry": {
    "copy_to": "geometryShape",
    "type": "geo_shape"
},
"geometryShape": {
    "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }
}
```

also

```
"geometry": {
    "copy_to": "geometryShape",
    "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }
},
"geometryShape": {
    "type": "geo_shape"
}
```

Any ideas on how to create this index properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If scripting is enabled then you could achieve it via specifying [transforms](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) in mapping

would look something on these lines :

```
put test/test_type/_mapping
{
   "transform": {
      "script": "if (ctx._source['geometry']['coordinates']) ctx._source['test'] = ctx._source['geometry']['coordinates']",
      "lang": "groovy"
   },
   "properties": {
      "geometry": {
         "type": "geo_shape"
      },
      "coordinates": {
         "type": "geo_point"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @MattJanssen was curios doesn't the above approach work

Comment: It very well may solve the problem. I'm having to upgrade our Elasticsearch servers to test it, as transform is a new feature to 1.3. I will know before the bounty expires tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the innovative answer! This is great because we don't have to duplicate the data in our database in order to get the geo_shape and geo_point at the same time. I'll let Amine know that this worked well for us.

Comment: Some notes: Transform requires Elasticsearch 1.3+. 

Also, newer versions of ES have disabled inline Groovy scripts for security reasons. You need to save the script as a file, add it as an index, or turn off the security measure.

Comment: Note that mapping transforms were deprecated in elasticsearch 2.0 and [have been removed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/13657) in 5.0. According to the documentation there is currently no comparable feature other than transforming the property client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a [function_score_query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/function-score-query.html) and your original mapping with just the geo_shape. Elasticsearch docs suggest that [scoring by distance](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html#scoring-by-distance) is usually better than sorting by distance.

On another note, have you checked out using a geo_bounding_box with a geo_point? I'm not sure exactly what you're using the geo_shape type for but you may be able to replicate it using the bounding box. Check out an example [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html).

Comment: We're filtering by postal-code boundaries. The docs say we can't score based on geo_shape; only geo_point. Which puts us back at the same problem.